# Angular HTTP Error 431 when using window.open() with ecoded data

Tags: angular, http

In an Angular I have a printable component page that needs to be opened externally to let the user print some statistics data.
The way it is built is by encoding the relevant data, and passing it in the URL.
[image]
However, when data gets really large, I encounter an HTTP Error 431, request header fields too large.

I am referring to the same application, so is there any way to disable / increase the max length threshold, or do I have to rework / workaround the implementation?
[image]

Comment: Is the data rendered by the backend or by angular as well?

Comment: Data is rendered in a normal Angular component in the same SPA, however in a new window, and with data passed as encoded URL string parameter. If that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit for the size of the URL which is about 2-64kb, depending on the browser.

But servers usually restrict the request headers and therefore the request path size to much smaller values to prevent denial of service attacks.

If you render the data only client side, you can use the fragment identifier ( `http://example.com/foo#<data>` ) since that data is not sent to the server.

If that does not solve the problem you use other means to propagate the data, for example through cross window messaging or storing the value in localstorage and just transport a unique id to the newly opened window.

Comment: Using fragment identifier solved my issue! :)